# In the shapeways api in nodejs how can I store access token?

Tags: node.js, api, 3d

Everytime I open website in a browser I seem to need to give authorization. There's no documentation on how to store access token so anybody can visit my website without having to authorize anything.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If users are going to get access to their personal shapewaays data using your application the user has to be sent to shapeways login page with your app token to grant your application access. If you have a callback url specified in that request your callback will receive the oauth secret and key for your app to use in the API to access users shapeway data.

If callback not specified a verifier code is shown on the page and if fed back by user to your app it can be used in further calls to the API to get the users oauth secrte and key.

Easiest is to use callback, but if you have a stand alone app with no web server to respond to callback the verifier code has to be typed in or captured from the user login page.

The sample code supplied by Shapeways in .NET is not that expressive and does not show implementations of model file uploads but give a hint on the oauth process up to the point user account can be accessed.

The keys for each user can be stored by your app and used until expired if they stop working user has to be sent again to shapeways granting page to grant your application access again.